# Typescript breakpoints not hit when debugging in WebStorm 7

Tags: debugging, typescript, breakpoints, webstorm

I am using Typescript SDK 0.9.1.1 and WebStorm 7.  I have a .ts file with a file watcher transpiling its .js and sourcemap files.  I also have an HTML file that looks like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p id="output">5</p>
    <script src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
    <script>
        var u = new Utils();
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = u.plusOne(5);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The plusOne function simply takes the number (in this case, 5) and returns that number plus one.  My page, javascript and Typescript work fine, because the page says "6" when loaded.

I can set breakpoints in the .js file and they are hit (showing me the Typescript file's equivalent line) but if I set breakpoints in the original .ts file they are not.  I've searched for this issue but my problem seems different from others' - I am running locally (not remotely) and I am setting the breakpoints in WebStorm, not Chrome's debug view.

In WebStorm, the Scripts tab shows only the .js and .html files.  Should I be seeing more here?  If that's the problem, how do I fix it?  I've opened the debug configuration but I don't see a way to add the .ts file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is due to an [open bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6413) in WebStorm.  In practical terms, the workaround is to reload the HTML page from the browser (which is NOT the same as rerunning the HTML page in debug mode from WebStorm).  If you do that then the breakpoints in the .ts file will be hit.

Comment: hmm same issue here, but not getting it to work. only way I get Webstorm to stop at all is by typing "debugger;" in the code, but still that only brings me to the .js file, not the .ts

Answer (score 7):

Some of you might have ended up here from Google:

All I had to do was make sure that `sourceMap` was set to `true` in my `tsConfig.json` like so:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```